# Whole column background formatted the same manner with openpyxl doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

MRE:

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

# Create a new workbook
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

# Select the active sheet
sheet = workbook.active

# Set the background color of the third column to black
fill = PatternFill(start_color='000000', end_color='000000', fill_type='solid')
for cell in sheet['C']:
    cell.fill = fill

# Save the workbook
workbook.save('example.xlsx')
```

Only the first cell of column 'C' is with black background.

I want the whole column to be formatted with black background (like it works in Excel when you format the whole column).

I don't want to iterate through cells from 1 to a big number because otherwise the Excel file created is created with loads of rows. It should be that the format is applied to the whole column **without creating new rows**, like it works in Excel basically. Is that possible? Or do I need to run `xlwings` to call a `VBA` function?

Comment: Its a new workbook so empty rows, therefore **for cell in sheet['C']:** is only going to select cell C1. Openpyxl works cell by cell, you'd need to specify some range.

Comment: Yeh I know, but I wanted to find a way to work without working cell by cell, I guess openpyxl is just not up to date on the latest excel versions allowing to manipulate whole columns at once even if the empty cells?

Comment: The way Openpyxl and Xlwings work is siginificantly different. Both have their pros and cons but ultimately are restricted by the interfaces used.

Comment: I guess using both is perfectly fine and gives me the best of both worlds :)

Comment: Formats **must always** be applied to individual cells. This is covered in the documentation.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yeh, I believed that openpyxl had addressed its limited features. But I was wrong!

Comment: It's **not** a limitation. The specification requires that formats are applied to all cells individually.

Comment: Yes of course! I'm just saying there are some features present in Excel not present in openpyxl but present in Xlwings! And I thought openpyxl had included them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly Xlwings can do it, without a VBA function.
Just do

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book()
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws.range('C:C').color = (0,0,0)
```

[xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings)